# Google Appengine Static files Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-app-engine

In our application hosted on GAE (Java), I am intermittently getting the ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error, for a few static files (css, json, etc). The Network tab in the browser usually shows 0 Bytes for the file for which the decoding failed.

It is more predominant in HTTPS mode, and very few times in the http mode. The Logging section of app engine console doesn't provide much information. It does log the requests for the static file accesses, but nothing more than that. The logging shows different numbers for each requests, and 0 bytes on a lot of requests.

Is there something that we are doing wrong with respect to static files + https?

A 2015-11-27 13:00:15.841  204     **752 B**    1 ms /manifest.json
  182.73.224.148 - - [26/Nov/2015:23:30:15 -0800] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 204 752 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36" "www.-----.com" ms=1 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=8.4041999999999993e-05 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.30 trace_id=735f1b4f40f2c5ee37dbf8978877e829

A 2015-11-27 13:00:45.094  204     **466 B**    1 ms /manifest.json
  10.35.9.140 - - [26/Nov/2015:23:30:45 -0800] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.0" 204 466 - "-" "www.-----.com" ms=1 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=5.2079e-05 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.30 trace_id=-

A 2015-11-27 13:00:45.095  304       **0 B**    1 ms /manifest.json
  182.73.224.148 - - [26/Nov/2015:23:30:45 -0800] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.0" 304 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36" "www.-----.com" ms=1 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.30 trace_id=-

A 2015-11-27 13:03:14.575  204     **608 B**    1 ms /manifest.json
  10.35.59.147 - - [26/Nov/2015:23:33:14 -0800] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.0" 204 608 - "-" "www.-----.com" ms=1 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=6.7949e-05 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.30 trace_id=-

Comment: Is ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in the appengine app or an application consuming the static files.  Also look at the HTTP Status codes, your 0 B log entries have a status code of 304 which means the content is not modified so use the cache, hence 0 bytes retrieved.  I think your need to describe your application a bit better.

Comment: Our application is [link](http://www.pycker.com). It is a web application, I am getting these exceptions in browser's (Google/Firefox) consoles. Some of my scripts and css files are receiving these, which is breaking the whole UI. Example this json (one of the many files that fail) fails frequently [link](https://www.pycker.com/manifest.json). This seems to be a very new phenomenon.

Comment: But a 304 response is not a new behaviour. Its always been there.  You should look at how these assets are being requested by the browser.  Look at your headers  you can set cache control in app.yaml and no doubt in your java definition .  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Static_cache_expiration

Comment: Also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451905/google-app-engine-not-generating-304-instead-generating-200-always

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is pagespeed. Google deprecated/shutdown pagespeed, but the option for it is not found in the new google appengine console. Heading to the older console, and flushing the pagespeed cache fixed the issue for us.

Wonder why static files are served from pagespeed servers even when this is shutdown.